# Oracle SQL - substr matching of disparate ID formats

Tags: sql, oracle, pattern-matching, substring

29664**A120091** ------ HR**A 120091** (CITYNAME)

90402**A12466** ------  HR**A 12466** (CITYNAME)

I need to query two fields to find ID matches from disparate formats.

First field on the left, the ID begins with an alha character mid-string, not always 'A', but the alpha plus everything to its right is the good ID.
Second field on the right, it's the third alpha (again can be any letter), remove the first space after that alpha, plus all the digits up to the second space.
If I've formatted correctly here the matching IDs are in bold. It's just beyond my substring chops.  Any assistance appreciated!

Comment: Can you specify the more table details about primary key etc?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  SUBSTR( value1, 6, 1 ) || ' ' || SUBSTR( value1, 7 )
         = SUBSTR( value2, 3, INSTR( value2, ' ', 1, 2 ) - 3 );
```

Or regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR( value1, '[A-Z]\d+$' )
         = REGEXP_REPLACE( value2, '^..([A-Z]) (\d+) .*$', '\1\2' )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value1, value2 ) AS
SELECT '29664A120091', 'HRA 120091 (CITYNAME)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '90402A12466',  'HRA 12466 (CITYNAME)'  FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> VALUE1       | VALUE2               
> :----------- | :--------------------
> 29664A120091 | HRA 120091 (CITYNAME)
> 90402A12466  | HRA 12466 (CITYNAME)
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2c65132fa23df0d4bda852646183bf70)*

Comment: MT0 - Outstanding, thank you!  REGEXP_SUBSTR solution appears to work great - where's the 'buy that person a beer' functionality here?